# List.builder lost images loading from web when scrolling

Tags: android, flutter, listview

I saw many questions related to this topic. When I try to load some images from the web, the list.builder loads them, but when I scroll they disappear and don't load again. I saw some examples, but it loads them again.
Try increasing the list.builder cache, cache_network_image, and reducing the image size, same result.
The widget disappears, and does not load until I start the screen again.

The child PrimaryCard disappears.

I think it may have to do with the streambuilder, since the widget disappears and the loading appears

```
child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: news.newsStream,
          builder: (context,AsyncSnapshot<List<News>> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData){
              return ListView.builder(
                cacheExtent: 1500,
                itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => ReadNewsView(news: snapshot.data![index]),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 12.0),
                      child:  PrimaryCard(news: snapshot.data![index]),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              );
            }
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          },
        ),
```

In PrimaryCard I get the images like this:

```
child: CachedNetworkImage(
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              imageUrl: news.url_image,
              maxHeightDiskCache: 100,
              maxWidthDiskCache: 100,
            ),
```

Comment: and why are you using 3rd party `CachedNetworkImage` and not `Image.network`?

Comment: Because I thought it would help with the cache..but, i will need it later

Comment: Thanks for they information, but...any idea about the problem?

Comment: The standard behaviour of the ListView.builder constructor is to create items as they’re scrolled onto the screen - instead of creating them all at once. Do you get an error message?

Comment: I have not had any errors. Analyzing better, it seems that it has to do with the streamBuilder, because the loading (CircularProgressIndicator) starts, and does not finish

Comment: add `print(snaphot);` before `if (snapshot.hasData){ ...` and check the logs